# catching SelectedIndexChanged of a dropdown list inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, repeater

I am trying to catch the SelectedIndexChanged of a DropDownList inside a Repeater. I have searched the internet but could not find a specific answer any help would be great. This is my code.

### page.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater id="CategoryMyC" OnItemCommand="SomeEvent_ItemCommand" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table><tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Edit Carousel Item</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Choose a product:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMcProducts" 
                                          DataTextField="Name"
                                          onselectedindexchanged="MyListIndexChanged"
                                          AutoPostBack="true"  
                                          DataSource='<%# ProductsManager.GetMerchantProductRepeater(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("MID"))) %>'  
                                          runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>                          
        </td>                
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tr>
     </table>
     </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

### page.aspx.cs

In the Page_Load:

```
List<CarouselProducts> CP = CarouselProductsManager.GetCarouselItems(Convert.ToInt32(Session["Mid"]));
CategoryMyC.DataSource = CP;
CategoryMyC.ItemDataBound += new  RepeaterItemEventHandler(RepeaterItemDataBound);
CategoryMyC.DataBind();
```

Other events:

```
protected void ddlMcProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList d = (DropDownList)sender;
    // Use d here

    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("I am changing");
}

protected virtual void PageInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get all the Carousel item of the merchant
    List<CarouselProducts> CP = CarouselProductsManager.GetCarouselItems(Convert.ToInt32(Session["Mid"]));
    //MerchantCategoryMyCarousel.DataSource = CP;
    //MerchantCategoryMyCarousel.DataBind();

    MerchantCategoryMyCarousel.DataSource = CP;
    MerchantCategoryMyCarousel.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(RepeaterItemDataBound);
    MerchantCategoryMyCarousel.DataBind();
}

protected virtual void RepeaterItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList theDropDown = sender as DropDownList;
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)
    {
        DropDownList MyList = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlMcProducts");
        if (MyList == null)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Did not find the controle");
        }
        else
            MyList.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(MyListIndexChanged);
    }
}

protected virtual void MyListIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("I am changing");
}

protected void SomeEvent_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandSource.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
    {
        DropDownList ddlSomething = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlSomething");
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("I am changing");
        //Now you can access your list that fired the event
        //SomeStaticClass.Update(ddlSomething.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

I need to catch the SelectedIndexChanged of the populated DropDownList for each one generated.

Comment: You have added windows form code in the code behind. Why? Cut it out!

Comment: are you sure MyListIndexChanged isn't being called and what is the use of ddlMcProducts_SelectedIndexChanged in your code?

Answer (score 3):

You've got quite a mismatch of code going on here - using System.Windows.Forms in an ASP.NET application is just one of the issues.  You appear to be assigning event handlers in the code-behind and in the markup (nothing necessarily bad about that, but there's seems to be no rhyme or reason to how you're doing it).

You're Repeater's ItemCommand event is bound to a method that is looking for a DropDownList that has a different ID than the one in your markup.

If you're using the System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox to debug (ala old school JavaScript and other language "debugging" methods), save yourself a world-class headache (not to mention a lot of unnecessary code cleanup when you're done with development) and step through your code in the debugger.

I'm not sure how the page will render, but I don't think you're using the HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate quite the way they're intended.

All that said, try something like this:

**Markup (ASPX page)**:

```
<asp:Repeater id="CategoryMyC" OnItemCommand="CategoryMvC_ItemCommand"  OnItemDataBound="CategoryMvC_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Edit Carousel Item</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>Choose a product:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMcProducts" 
                                      DataTextField="Name"
                                      OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMcProducts_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                      AutoPostBack="true"  
                                      DataSource='<%# ProductsManager.GetMerchantProductRepeater(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("MID"))) %>'  
                                      runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>                                          
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code Behind (APSX.CS)**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<CarouselProducts> CP = CarouselProductsManager.GetCarouselItems(Convert.ToInt32(Session["Mid"]));
    CategoryMyC.DataSource = CP;
    //This can be assigned in the markup
    //CategoryMyC.ItemDataBound += new  RepeaterItemEventHandler(RepeaterItemDataBound);
    CategoryMyC.DataBind();
}

protected void ddlMcProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList d = (DropDownList)sender;
    // Use d here
}

protected void CategoryMyC_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    DropDownList theDropDown = sender as DropDownList;

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)
    {
        DropDownList MyList = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlMcProducts");

        // This section is not needed for what you are doing with it:
        // If the control is null, handle it as an error
        // There's no need to give it an event handler if it does exist, because
        // you already did so in the markup
        //if (MyList == null)
        //{
            //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Did not find the controle");
        //}
        //else
            //MyList.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(MyListIndexChanged);
        //}
    }
}

protected void CategoryMyC_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandSource.GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
    {
        // Note the correct control name is being passed to FindControl
        DropDownList ddlSomething = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlMcProducts");
        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("I am changing");
        //Now you can access your list that fired the event
        //SomeStaticClass.Update(ddlMcProducts.SelectedIndex);
}
```

There may be more issues at hand as well - but this will hopefully streamline it enough for you to make some progress.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void drpOrganization_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)ddl.NamingContainer;
        if (item != null)
        {
            CheckBoxList list = (CheckBoxList)item.FindControl("chkSite");
            if (list != null)
            { 

            }
        }
    }
```